# Erro Repository Spring de Entidade com Relacionamentos

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

Estou com um projeto usando Spring Boot para servir JSON em um WebService.
Um erro ocorreu quando adiciono a classe de Repository. Se removê-la o programa inicia normalmente (sem erros no console, não falo de funcionalidades).

O erro é: http://www.cjoint.com/c/FGir7xhZgvR (coloquei no Cjoint por ser muito grande).

As classes são:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface Sells extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Long, Sell> {

}

@Entity
public class Sell implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Date sellDate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sell", targetEntity = SellItem.class,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SellItem> sellItems;
    private Double total;
    // Getters e setter omitidos
}

@Entity
public class SellItem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;
    private Integer quantity;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sell_id")
    private Sell sell;
    //Getters e setter omitidos
}
```

Caso necessário, peça mais informações nos comentários.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, não sei se você já identificou o seu problema. Dei uma olhada no erro e vi que você declarou o seu repository da seguinte maneira:

```
public interface Sells extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Long, Sell> {
}
```

Sendo que a maneira correta é:

```
public interface Sells extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Sell, Long> {
}
```

Pelo que me parece você só inverteu a ordem dos argumentos genéricos da interface *PagingAndSortingRepository*.